# iterate over every key in nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Is there a simple way to iterate over every key in a nested hash.  I have a large json and I just want the values of certain keys, no matter what level they are at.  It also doesn't matter who their parent is.  Looking for a way to just straight line iterate though each key and return the values of keys that equal a specific string.

Comment: provide some input and desired output please

Answer (score 2):

```
module HashNestedGet
  refine Hash do
    def nested_get(key)
      return fetch(key) if has_key?(key)
      each do |subkey, subval|
        if Hash === subval
          result = subval.nested_get(key)
          return result if result
        end
      end
      nil        
    end
  end
end

a = { b: 1, c: { d: { e: 2 } } }
using HashNestedGet
require 'pp'
pp a.nested_get(:b)
# => 1
pp a.nested_get(:e)
# => 2
pp a.nested_get(:d)
# => nil
```

(posted as refinement, so it won't work in `irb`; easy enough to make into a plain function if necessary)