# How to recursively check for presence of specific key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, hash

Given a Ruby hash of parameters that are infinitely nested, I want to write a function that returns `true` if a given key is in those parameters.

This is the function I have so far, but it's not quite right, and I'm at a loss as to why:

```
def has_key(hash, key)
    hash.each do |k, v|
        if k == key
            return true
        elsif v.class.to_s == "Array"
            v.each do |inner_hash|
                return has_key(inner_hash,key)
            end
        else 
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

The method should return the following results:

```
# all check for presence of "refund" key

has_key({
  "refund" => "2"
}, "refund")
=> true

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3"
}, "refund")
=> false

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3", 
  "child_attributes" => [{
     "refund" => "1"
  }]
}, "refund")
=> true    

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3", 
  "child_attributes" => [{
    "nope" => "4"
  }]
}, "refund")
=> false

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3", 
  "child_attributes" => [{
    "a" => "1", 
    "refund" => "2"
  }]
}, "refund")
=> true

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3", 
  "child_attributes" => [
    {"a" => "1", "b" => "2"},
    {"aa" => "1", "refund" => "2"}
  ]
}, "refund")
=> true

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3", 
  "child_attributes" => [
    {"a" => "1", "b" => "2"},
    {"grand_child_attributes" => [
      {"test" => "3"}
    ]}
  ]
}, "refund")
=> false

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3", 
  "child_attributes" => [
    {"a" => "1", "b" => "2"},
    {"grand_child_attributes" => [
      {"test" => "3"}, {"refund" => "5"}
    ]}
  ]
}, "refund")
=> true

has_key({
  "whatever" => "3", 
  "child_attributes" => [
    {"a" => "1", "b" => "2"},
    {"grand_child_attributes" => [
      {"test" => "3", "refund" => "5"}
    ]}
  ]
}, "refund")
=> true
```

Comment: Inner hashes will always be wrapped in an array ?

Comment: yes, that's why i'm checking for array in the if function

Comment: check out my solution below. there's a tiny bug in your code

Comment: is there a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the hash to JSON and then check whether the JSON has `"refund":` present in it, as any key will be serialised to JSON in the form `"key":`.

```
require "json"
hash.to_json.include?('"refund":')
```

Comment: It's a smart end-run that almost solves the problem. It'll fail if a value matched the target key.

Comment: What if there is a key "refunded" or a value "refund"?

Comment: It'll ignore a key "refunded" because it's searching for `'"refund":'` but a value of `'"refund":'` will trick it.

Comment: @theTinMan I think use of `:` helps in matching against only keys, I have tried that scenario

Comment: @CarySwoveland If the value is `"refund":`, the output JSON will escape the quotes and it will look like `"\"refund\":"` and it will still be non-match

Comment: i like this for being incredibly brief and out of the boxy

Comment: Sorry, I missed the colon, so it can't be a value, but there still could be a key `"arefund"`. True, that's not a word, but we're not talking about the particular word "refund". I suggest you use the regular expression `/\brefund:/`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The quotes around `refund` is part of JSON, so if one was looking for `arefund`, the key will be `"arefund":` in JSON which is not going to match with `"refund":`.

Comment: Egad, not only did I miss the colon, but also the single and double quotes! Good one!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following will work.

```
def has_key(hash, key)
  hash.each do |k, v|
    return true if k == key
    if v.is_a? Array
      v.each do |h|
        rv = has_key(h, key)
        return rv if rv
      end
    end
  end
  false
end
```

This passes all your tests. One more:

```
h = { "a" => 1, 
      "b" => [{ "c" => 2, "d" => 3 },
              {"e"=> [{ "f" => "4" },
                      { "g" => [{ "h" => 5 },
                                { "i" => 6, "refund" => 7 }
                               ]
                      }             
                     ]
              }
             ]
    }

has_key h, "refund"
  #=> true

h["b"][1]["e"][1]["g"] = [{ "h"=>5 }] 
h
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>[{"c"=>2, "d"=>3}, {"e"=>[{"f"=>"4"}, {"g"=>[{"h"=>5}]}]}]} 
has_key h, "refund"
  #=> false
```

Inspired by @Wand's answer, for

```
h = {"a"=>"3", "b"=>[{"c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}, {"e"=>[{"test"=>"3", "refund"=>"5"}]}]}
```

you don't have to load JSON:

```
str = h.to_s
  #=> "{\"a\"=>\"3\", \"b\"=>[{\"c\"=>\"1\", \"d\"=>\"2\"}, {\"e\"=>[{\"test\"=>\"3\", \"refund\"=>\"5\"}]}]}" 
str =~ /\"refund\"=>/
  #=> 60 (truthy)
```

I confess to being a little uncomfortable with any approach that converts the hash to a string, and then parsing the string, for fear that string formats may change in future.

Comment: in theory i think this answer is totally right (someone else gave it as well). but in practice i can't get it to pass. i think i just have a typo somewhere... may need to take a look later

Comment: I don't see another answer that is the same as mine. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code seems to be in here:

```
elsif v.class.to_s == "Array"
    v.each do |inner_hash|
        return has_key(inner_hash,key)
    end
else
```

This would always return `has_key(inner_array[0])` without checking subsequent values. The fix is to return only if it's true, else continue checking, like this:

```
elsif v.class.to_s == "Array"
    v.each do |inner_hash|
        if(has_key(inner_hash,key))
            return true
        end
    end
else
    return false
```

Comment: does the solution work ? it seems logical enough to work. but i have some issues in my local machine i could not test it.

Comment: i don't know why.. i might be very obtuse here, but i tried this myself and it didn't work, so i asked on SO. another person had the exact same answer...

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
class Hash
  def key_exists?(key)
    self.keys.include?(key) ||
    self.values.any?{ |v|
      Hash === v &&
        v.key_exists?(key)
    }
  end
end

{'a' => 1}.key_exists?('a')  # => true
{'b' => 1}.key_exists?('a')  # => false
{'b' => {}}.key_exists?('a')  # => false

{'b' => {'a' => {}}}.key_exists?('a')  # => true
{'b' => {'a' => 1}}.key_exists?('a')  # => true

{'b' => {'b' => {}}}.key_exists?('a')  # => false
{'b' => {'b' => {'a' => 1}}}.key_exists?('a')  # => true
```

*Insert all the usual warnings about extending core classes and recommendations to use the alternative ways of doing it here.*

Note: Similarly, "[iterate over every key in nested hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178898/iterate-over-every-key-in-nested-hash/30179897#30179897)" could be used to easily determine a true/false value and it demonstrates the safe way to extend a core class.

Comment: This only works for one level of nesting. See the tests the OP gave. Also, the nesting appears to be associated with values being arrays.

Comment: It works for multiple levels. The last test hash is three nested hashes. The OP does use arrays of hashes but all instances are single hashes in the arrays. Dealing with that is a pretty simple change.

Comment: Ah, yes. I hadn't noticed that all the arrays in the test hashes contained only a single hash. We don't know if that is part of the specification, so you should perhaps give the proviso. In that case, however, interesting answer.

Comment: I see that some of the test problems have arrays containing multiple hashes, but I'd think you could deal with that. Why don't you edit your answer to deal with the general case?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, I tried it, seems to work fine for me

```
def has_key(hash, key)
  if hash.keys.include?(key)
    true
  else
    # get the values of the current hash, flatten out to not include arrays
    new_hash = hash.values.flatten
    # then filter out any element that's not a hash
    new_hash = new_hash.select {|b| b.is_a?(Hash)}
    # merge all the hashes into single hash
    new_hash = new_hash.inject {|first, second| first.merge(second)}

    if new_hash
      has_key(new_hash, key)
    else
      false
    end
  end
end
```